# Session is create and print in backend but not work in frontend

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-variables

I am facing some strange issue.

This problem happens on server. I am facing this problem since last 5-6 days. It was working for me until last 1 year.

When I call a login api, if user credential is right then I create a session.

Here is my code:

```
if ($user){
    if ($user['is_active'] == 1){
        global $user_data;
        $user_data = $user;
        $response["error"] = false;
        $_SESSION['user_data'] = $user; // -- session is create
        print_r($_SESSION); // session is print.

        $_SESSION['is_login'] = 'No';
        unset($_SESSION['sessionX']);
        $response['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
        $response['name'] = $user['name'];
        $response['email'] = $user['email'];
        $response['apiKey'] = $user['api_key'];
        $response['createdAt'] = $user['created_date'];

    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Your Account is Not Active';
    }
} else {
// user credentials are wrong
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Login failed. Incorrect credentials';
}
```

print_r of this portion:

```
Array
(
    [slim.flash] => Array
        (
        )

    [db_name] => arcade_intecigar
    [user_data] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [name] => zzz
            [email] => zzz@abc.com
            [api_key] => 3fef39209b3d03039cdb81d39566eb66
            [lang_id] => en_US
            [created_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [profile_pic] => ""
            [img] => 1461269872mk-ok.png
            [subscription_id] => 20
            [is_active] => 1
            [role_id] => 1
            [delete_permission] => 1
            [phone_number] => +14507013
            [country_code] => 1
            [total_usage_funds] => 0.0024999999441206
            [total_available_funds] => 0.99750000238419
            [paid] => trial
            [currency] => USD
        )

)
```

After login, I am redirecting my app to dashboard page and check that if session is available or not, but it is strange that session is not available. And it is always redirecting me to the login page.

Look below code.

```
print_r($_SESSION); // it is display a blank
if (!isset($_SESSION['is_login']) && !isset($_SESSION['is_lock'])) {
    echo "<script>window.location='" . SITE_URL . "login.php?redirect=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';</script>";
}
if (isset($_SESSION['is_login']) && $_SESSION['is_login'] == 'NO' || $_SESSION['is_login']== 'No') {
    echo "<script>window.location='" . SITE_URL . "login.php?redirect=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';</script>";
}
```

print_r of this portion:

```
Array ( [db_name] => arcade_intecigar )
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()`?

Comment: Also, you should probably be hashing your API keys instead of storing them in plain text. Try `password_hash()`.

Comment: my session is start in config.php file

Comment: Is that called before or after the second block of code is executed?

Comment: @Mike second block code is in to the dashboard page , which is redirect after login.

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` on every single request before you use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Mike it is working for me since last 1 year.

Comment: @Mike , i will try it

Comment: i put `session_start();` in login function , but it is display below error.
`Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
File: /var/www/html/api/v1/index.php
Line: 249`

Comment: OK, just making sure the session was actually being started. Try using another browser to see if it's a problem with your browser being configured to not accept session cookies.

Comment: i already try this in mozila , ie , ie edge and safari . Same problem

Comment: first of all check $_SESSION['testing']="just for checking ";  echo $_SESSION['testing']; and know that session function is working or not in your page

Comment: @chiragpatel Please post the output of `print_r(session_get_cookie_params());`

Comment: @Mike, this is the output :
`Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => [httponly] => ) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is happen because , on server there is no inode memory is avaiable for more session create , as per my knowledge when session is create in php that time session file is also create , so there is no memory is available that's why session is not create .

Use `df -i` command for know the inode memory on server.

Check this link for more description: https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html