# Php Login Session not Working

Tags: php, mysql, session

I really need your help. My `php` session is not working.

This is my login code.

```html
<?php  
session_start();
include_once('dbcon/connection.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    

  if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $error = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
           }  
           else  
           {

              $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_acc WHERE username=:uname AND password =:pword LIMIT 1");
              $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$_POST["email"],':pword'=>$_POST["password"]));
              $userRow = $stmt->fetch(); 
              if($userRow > 0)
              {
                 
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $userRow["user_id_session"]; 
                        header('location:dashboard.php');

              }else{
                 $error = '<label>Username or Password is incorrect</label>';  
              }
           }  
      }  
?>
```

This is my dashboad code.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Not working, it redirects to login page. What is the error and what should i do so that it is working?

PS: it is already working, the SESSION. But only today it is not working. I don't know why. I am not good in `php`. Sorry for my English.

Comment: did you start session in your login page?

Comment: Check if session is started with var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: this problem is occur on server or on local??

Comment: you need to start the session on this page as well and why are you storing the password as plain text?

Comment: @chiragsatapara it is on server. its working before, but today is not working

Comment: so you are using linux server ???

Comment: @BilalJohn where do i input the start_session in my login page? at the top of my code?

Comment: @chiragsatapara yes, i am using linux server

Comment: check this link , i have fetch same problem and here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284474/session-is-create-and-print-in-backend-but-not-work-in-frontend/39607947#39607947

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile im using plain text because i dont know how to set password on hash

Comment: then learn on the php.net site

Comment: @chiragsatapara thank you. but i dont get it.. what is "df -i " ?

Comment: @JorhendzStudios , let me know if you need more help from me, this is a link for brief descriptoin: https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html

Comment: @JorhendzStudios did u start the session on this page?

Comment: @chiragsatapara thank you. i will study it.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes, i already start the session, because it was working before, and i start login today its not working. my credentilas was correct but its redirect to login pages.

Comment: @JorhendzStudios , if my suggestion help to you, don't forgot to appreciate my work.

Comment: @JorhendzStudios , my suggestion is the solution , i spent almost 1 week to find this solution, and i am fetch the same problem , which you are fetching right now.

Comment: @chiragsatapara is there other methods to solve my issue?

Comment: @JorhendzStudios what does var_dump($_SESSION) show?

Comment: @JorhendzStudios, yes , change the instance size, like if you have `t2.micro` then move to `t2.medium` and one more solution is check this link , and follow the 3rd answer , for install `autoremove`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage?rq=1

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it say NULL :(

Comment: can you post the full login code please @JorhendzStudios

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile please see my edit post for full codes